# ua-x-compatible closest setting to IE8 Compat

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, iis-7.5

we're currently maintaining an enterprise application based on ASP.Net 3.5, MS Enterprise Lib 4.1 and Telerik ASP.Net AJAX 2010. The application consist of 2 different part, intranet and internet portion. We announced compatibility with IE6 and above and Firefox, back in 2011. It's been fine so far until IE10 and 11 came into the picture. Since launch, we've advise users to turn on compatibility mode for IE8 & 9. But for IE10, we found that we need to add App_Browser, and it still break certain pages.

Now we plan to provide support to IE9 and above so we've decided to update Telerik ASP.Net AJAX to the latest version. But during this transition period, we notice a lot of UI issues when switching between browsers. To minimized effort on updating every page, we want to try using "ua-x-compatible" in web.config to force all browser to render with the best fit rendering mode. But there's no mentioned of setting IE=6. We're wonder how to configure it so that all new IE browser switch into Compat view mode used by IE8. Another thing we notice is that with IE=8, there's minor differences in terms of look and feel when compare to using IE8 Compat View. We're trying to minimized the differences as much as possible, to preserve the user experience.

We also understand that in intranet, newer IE browser will fall back to Compat View automatically, but that doesn't seems to be the case for us.

If there's a direct answer to this, then I would really appreciate it, otherwise some direction would be a good starting point.

Thank you

Comment: If you have UI issues when switching between browsers, what you should be doing is switch to _edge_ mode. And what you also should be doing is forget about IE6. Tell yourself there is no IE6 and there never was.

Comment: So with all that in mind, make sure you are using a proper DOCTYPE and that your CSS doesn't assume anything about default settings. Use a reset stylesheet that defines all margins, box-sizings etc explicitly. Then if there still are differences between browsers, come back here and show the code that causes those differences.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister, I thought _edge_ means latest? It's not that we don't want to forget IE6(who wouldn't want to), but we have other integration part that we can't upgrade or we don't have control over. As for correcting the UI issue, it's not really a problem for us. Well, we're more into looking for a "shortcut" or some what easier solution for this transition which might take months, before we're ready to switch over to _edge_.

Answer (score 1):

We should no longer as community keep support for IE6[image]

Several communities are promoting to remove total support for this browser.

http://www.ie6death.com/

But I understand this not always I call we can make. I would recommend you to try :

http://modernizr.com/docs/#support

This will polyfill your javascript and will help you with your browser support.